# Mysql show different columns for different where clauses

Tags: mysql

I want to show a output table that counts all the users found in a table. 
Basically I want the output to look like:

```
+-----------+-----------+
| user1     | user2     |
+-----------+-----------+
|         5 |         2 |
+-----------+-----------+
```

I'm just using a dummy table to test this. My query looks like this:

```
(
    select 
        name as user1 
    from 
        users 
    where 
        name = 'root'
) UNION (
    select 
        name as user2 
    from
        users 
    where 
        name = 'not_root'
)
```

Which only outputs something like this:

```
+-----------+
| user1     |
+-----------+
|         5 |
|         2 |
+-----------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDITED**

The main idea of the approach it's treat a table as two different virtual tables in subquery. We can make nested select statement e.g. `(select count(*) as c from users where name = 'root') u1` MySql treats it as particular table named `u1` with one row and one column named `c`.

```
select u1.c as root_cnt, u2.c as not_root_cnt
from (select count(*) as c from users where name = 'root') u1,
(select count(*) as c from users where name = 'not_root') u2
```

or

Moreover if you have select statement that returns only one row you can put nested selects directly in fields list

```
select (select count(*) as c from users where name = 'root') as root_cnt, (select count(*) as c from users where name = 'not_root') as not_root_cnt
```

Definite disadvantage of such approach it's extra subqueries. Method based on using [`case when`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26470748/532208) construction free from such disadvantage.

Comment: This actually gave me the answer I was looking for. Can you please add a little description for how this works? I want to understand why this is happening since I'm a total newbie.

Comment: Also, I couldn't get `count(u1.*)` to work (syntax error), I had to go with `count(u1.name)`.

Comment: @DumbAsker Indeed looks like count(u1.*) doesn't work. I've refined query and add one other with using the same approach.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN Name = 'root' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) user1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Name = 'not_root' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) user2
FROM Users
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `case` statement inside of `count` to get the counts in separate columns

```
select
    count(case when name = 'root' then 1 end) user1,
    count(case when name = 'not_root' then 1 end) user2
from users
where name in ('root','not_root')
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems your query is wrong..

union won't combine the results of two queries in the way you have described above.

union would combine the result of two or more select statements but wouldn't "join" it.

You might want to use joins for this cause. still you wouldn't be able to put 5|2 in same row as it basically suggests --> fetch user 1 and user 2 values for one particular type

Answer (score 0):

i think group by is a much better approach:

`select user, count(user) from users group by user`